# R 'merge' is changing data in the merging dataframes

Tags: r, merge

I am having some trouble with the merge command in R, I am trying to place values into bins that I can then use as color values for a plot. I would like to keep the quantile bin values though to use as a legend, so I am merging that back to the original dataframe as well.

The problem I have is that when I do this the original values get changed when I merge the quantiles back to the original dataframe to make a new dataframe. I am probably doing something obviously wrong, but have been toying with this problem for some time now and searching 'merge is changing data' does not return anything on the type of unintentional 'changing data' I am having trouble with. Thanks!

```
# create random data
x=rnorm(100,100,25)
x=as.data.frame(x)

# create bins to place the data in
quantiles=quantile(x,c(seq(.05,.95,.05)))
quantiles=as.data.frame(quantiles)

# create bin number to merge upon later
quantiles$binnumber=c(1:dim(quantiles)[1])

# create bin number in x to merge upon later
x$binnumber=tapply(x$x,cut(x$x,quantiles$quantiles))

merged=merge(x,quantiles,by="binnumber")

# should work right? note the difference in summary,
# it seems the high and low values got changed
# somehow while the middle values did not.

summary(x$x)

  Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 39.35   83.15   95.67   98.92  116.30  190.80 

summary(merged$x)

  Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 60.62   84.46   95.67   97.92  114.20  136.40
```

Comment: Is there a `merged[["x.x"]]`? There is probably a name clash here.

Comment: Try `all = TRUE` when you merge?

Comment: I think you might want to change how you're using `cut`, as well, unless you intended for many of the `x` values to not be assigned to a bin.

Comment: 'all=TRUE' seems to be working. @joran I have changed the 'cut'  part to be for quantiles going from 0 to 1 rather than starting at .05 and ending at .95, is that what you meant?

Comment: No, I meant using `Inf` and `-Inf` as described in the answer below, but that might work too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is

```
x$binnumber = tapply(x$x,cut(x$x,quantiles$quantiles))
```

Note that this results in NA values in `x$binnumber`. This is because `quantiles$quantiles` only goes up to the .95 quantile and there are values of `x` above that. Since those values are outside the range of breaks you specified, they are set as NA. and when you go to merge on binnumber, you cannot merge the NA values.

You could fix this by making the quantiles go to 1

```
quantiles <- quantile(x,c(seq(.05,1.00,.05)))
```

and including all values lower than the lowest quantile in the cut

```
x$binnumber <- tapply(x$x,cut(x$x,c(-Inf, quantiles$quantiles)))
```

Doing so should give you matching values

```
summary(merged$x)
#    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#   43.34   83.46  105.30  102.60  121.20  170.50 

summary(x$x)
#    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#   43.34   83.46  105.30  102.60  121.20  170.50
```

Comment: Thanks! Would having the quantile sequence start at 0 rather than .05 `quantiles <- quantile(x,c(seq(0,1.00,.05)))` accomplish the same thing as including -Inf in tapply?

Comment: I tried that but it seemed to make an extra group in the x bin numbers. I didn't spend enough time to figure out why. Maybe I had something else wrong too. It's worth a shot.

Comment: @user3745597 Just got another change to try it. Yes, you can set the qualties to go from 0 to 1, then you just need tomake sure to do `x$binnumber=tapply(x$x,cut(x$x,quantiles$quantiles, include.lowest=T))` (add the `include.lowest=` parameter)